# Unable to run Magento 2 Web Setup on nginx

Tags: magento2, web-setup-wizard

I've downloaded Magento 2 and try to setup but getting blank page.

When I have checked `nginx` log file and I found below the log.

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script
>   '/var/www/html/magento2/demo/setup/index.php/navigation' has been
>   denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header
>   from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 224.example.com, request:
>   "GET /setup/index.php/navigation HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "224.example.com",
>   referrer: "http://224.example.com/setup/"; 2018/05/23 16:58:47
>   [error] 18961#18961: 319 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script
>   '/var/www/html/magento2/demo/setup/index.php/navigation/side-menu' has
>   been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response
>   header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 224.example.com,
>   request: "GET /setup/index.php/navigation/side-menu HTTP/1.1",
>   upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "224.example.com", referrer: "http://224.example.com/setup/";
>   2018/05/23 16:58:47 [error] 18959#18959: *377 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "Access to the script
>   '/var/www/html/magento2/demo/setup/index.php/navigation/header-bar'
>   has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading
>   response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server:
>   224.example.com, request: "GET /setup/index.php/navigation/header-bar HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "224.example.com", referrer: "http://224.example.com/setup/";

If anyone faces the same issue then help me.

Comment: I saw you solved your problem, gj! 
A small advice from me, did you try to run the installation from command line ? I think it's a lot simpler, and you don't got trubles reinstalling Magento 2 later on, you just tap 2 commands (uninstall/install)
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

Comment: Hi guys I have the same problem with Magento 2.4.0 and I don't have a Web setup wizard Icon
I will appreciate it if someone helps me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved:

Changed nginx.conf.sample setup location block to:

Default Magento nginx.conf.sample file need to replace.

```
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}
```

Replace with:

```
location /setup {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {

        ### This fixes the problem:
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        ################################

        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}
```

Found solution from [git](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2504)

Answer (score 2):

No need to Replace whole code in `nginx.conf.sample` just replace  `location ~* ^/setup($|/)` to `location  ^/setup($|/)` .

Because issue is  `~*` sign before setup Url, browser doesn't understand this

Comment: After updated =>location  ^/setup($|/) then run installation command => https://justpaste.it/6o2cz and my output => https://snipboard.io/zLAehy.jpg, how to solve my issue?

Comment: my magento.conf => https://justpaste.it/30n8n