# After upgrade magento 2.2.4 to 2.2.6 web setup wizard not display

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.2.6, web-setup-wizard

I have just upgrade magento 2.2.4 to 2.2.6 and noticed that web setup wizard not display.

It was displayed in 2.2.4 found that already reported here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7623

Does anyone have the idea what if I supposed to do to re-appear this tab?
I think Magento will consider it in next release.

Comment: try to set permission to magento directories and then check.

Comment: I set permission like **find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && chmod 777 ./app/etc && chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml** but seems nothing happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got a solution from this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/227175)

So I am describing what I supposed to be followed

1) First I followed @Rohan Hapani's solution like hiding below method

```
/**
 * Removes 'Web Setup Wizard' from the menu if doc root is pub and no setup url variable is specified.
 *
 * @param Builder $subject
 * @param Menu $menu
 * @return Menu
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
public function afterGetResult(Builder $subject, Menu $menu)
{
    if ($this->docRootLocator->isPub()) {
        $menu->remove('Magento_Backend::setup_wizard'); //You can comment this line / function to show it.
    }
    return $menu;
}
```

2) After that, I followed this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/227175/55928)

To replace

```
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
....
}
```

with

```
location /setup {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {

        ### This fixes the problem:
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        ################################

        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}
```

into **nginx.conf.sample** of Magento root folder

run below command

> sudo service nginx restart && sudo service php7.1-fpm restart
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope other can get help from this post if they faced same problem.

**NOTE**: as this is the temporary solution until Magento fix in next release(reference issue link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7623)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's come from `/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Setup/MenuBuilder.php` file :

```
/**
 * Removes 'Web Setup Wizard' from the menu if doc root is pub and no setup url variable is specified.
 *
 * @param Builder $subject
 * @param Menu $menu
 * @return Menu
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 * @since 100.1.0
 */
public function afterGetResult(Builder $subject, Menu $menu)
{
    if ($this->docRootLocator->isPub()) {
        $menu->remove('Magento_Backend::setup_wizard'); //You can comment this line / function to show it.
    }
    return $menu;
}
```

But, as per my view it's just temporary solution.

So, try to follow this way.

Go to `public_html/app/etc/env.php` and change the following code from

```
'session' => [
'save' => 'db'
```

to

```
'session' => [
'save' => 'files'
```

---

**EDIT :**
I think in your magento, update folder not create.

Don't forget that you must have 2 doc roots for your website and setup.

```
## Set Magento root folder
set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
## Set main public directory /pub
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
```

...

```
location ~ ^/(setup|update) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
```

[Reference](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4159#issuecomment-244483087)

Hope, it may be helpful for you.

Comment: In my case session already saved into files like as you mentioned

Comment: okay. You can comment that function as i mention that it's temporary solution.

Comment: can you please let me know what's the pros cons if we override **afterGetResult** method and remove **$menu->remove('Magento_Backend::setup_wizard');** line

I just hide **$menu->remove('Magento_Backend::setup_wizard');** line  tab is appear but after click on tab it seems as a blank page

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: I have added your edited changes into **nginx.conf.sample** file,  but still it's not working. I am using nginx server. by the way update folder is already created for me

Comment: sorry bro. I just know these things. Still, I will find and give solution. Currently, this things work from my side so. Still, try to upgrade and di compile.

Comment: I think after di compile it will be running.

Comment: Ok let me try it

Comment: it's not working after di compile :( no worry thanks for your time